# flutter dropdown not storing select value

Tags: flutter

I have flutter dropdown select list:

as

```
ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.local_shipping),
        title: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: serviceProvider,
          // hint: const Text('Select Service Provider'),
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              serviceProvider = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: <Map>[{"id":"1","business_name":'Business Name 1'}, {"id":"3","business_name":'Business Name 3'}, {"id":"6","business_name":'Business Name 6'}, {"id":"5","business_name":'Business Name 5'}].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value['id'],
              child: Text(value['business_name']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        ),
```

If i decleare `String serviceProvider = "6";` it just work fine. but after selecting one item from list it doest not persist there.

I am not able to figure out what's missing in my code,

Thanks
")

Comment: it work completely fine for me.

Comment: It works 100% for me. So no idea where it goes wrong for you